# i had upload file and some field items to document library i have made one field mandatory in that field but even then i am able to upload file

Tags: sharepoint-2010

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

```
                    SPFolder folder = web.Folders["ContractorDetails"];
                    SPFileCollection filecol = folder.Files;
                    Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                    byte[] contents = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength)];
                    SPFile addedFile = filecol.Add(filename, contents, replaceExistingFiles);
                    SPItem newItem = addedFile.Item;
                    newItem["Title"] = ddlTitle.SelectedValue;
                    newItem["First Name"] = tbFirstName.Text;
                    newItem["Middle Name"] = tbMiddleName.Text;
                    newItem["Last Name"] = tbLastName.Text;
                    newItem["NT User Name"] = tbNtuser.Text;
                    newItem["Contract Firm"] = tbContractFirm.Text;
                    newItem["Employee Type"] = tbEmpType.Text;
                    newItem["Division"] = ddlDivision.SelectedValue;
                    newItem["Location"] = ddlLocation.SelectedValue;
                    newItem["Contract Start Date"] = dateTimeStart.SelectedDate;
                    newItem["Contract End Date"] = dateTimeEnd.SelectedDate;
                    newItem["Project Term"] = Convert.ToInt32(tbProjectTerm.Text);
                   // newItem["Manager"] = PeopleEditor1.t
                    newItem["Comments"] = tbcomments.Text;
                    newItem.Update();
                    addedFile.Update();


                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try to upload file from UI to check field is mandatory or not?

Comment: I mean to say are you able to upload file from UI without mandatory field ?